# -1 from a value in an do while loop

Tags: apex

I have a while loop that makes one number go higher and i'm using the num ++ function but i cant seem to take away a number from a value using a similar expression eg. num -- . Is there a way of getting that number down by one in a do while loop?

```
public class GenerateNumber {

    public String numbersgenerated {get;set;}
    public Integer userinput {get;set;}
    public Decimal largenum {get;set;}
    list<Number_Setting__c> cslist = [SELECT Largest_Number__c FROM Number_Setting__c]; 

    public void  genumber() {

        do {
            if(cslist.size() > 0)
                largeNum = cslist[0].Largest_Number__c;
            largeNum ++;

            for (Number_Setting__c updt : cslist) {
                updt.Largest_Number__c = largeNum; 
                update updt; 
            }

        } while(userinput >  0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer i = 10;
do {
  system.debug(i--);
} while (i > 0);`

Comment: Mind sharing your code?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: where is your `--` part code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The i-- operator works fine. It evaluates the expiration and then reduces value.

So if you execute :

```
Integer i = 5;
system.debug(' i = '+ i--);
```

It will print 5.

but if you add one more debug you will see expected result.

```
Integer i = 5;
system.debug(' i = '+ i--);
system.debug(' i = '+ i);
```

So, the point is, in first debug it print the i and then reduces its value.

When you print it again in 2nd debug that time you see effect.

If you don't want it to execute the statement and then detriment the value you should use --i instead of i--